# Laradock localstack can't access s3 local file (error 403)

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laradock, localstack

I can't access a file created in a docker container with localstack (that mimics aws S3)

I see that it exists if I access localstack:5000, but if I actually go to it I get 403

```
<Contents>
<Key>json/fa8bd17360193232d16a031b977387e7.json</Key>
<LastModified>2020-08-04T08:35:46.000Z</LastModified>
<ETag>"fa8bd17360193232d16a031b977387e7"</ETag>
<Size>6593</Size>
<StorageClass>STANDARD</StorageClass>
<Owner>
<ID>75aa57f09aa0c8caeab4f8c24e99d10f8e7faeebf76c078efc7c6caea54ba06a</ID>
<DisplayName>webfile</DisplayName>
</Owner>
</Contents>
```

And if I try to access it:

```
Access to localstack.test was deniedYou don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

I also tried finding the file on the docker container, with `find / -name "FILE NAME"` with no luck ..

Any ideas ?

Comment: You need to make these files as public files on your s3 or use a professional way by attaching a role to the s3 who can read it and use this role to access the data from your app

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan I made the bucket public ...

Comment: make sure that the files inside it are public too